# Como usar enum com hierarquia / aninhamento de agrupamento e subgrupo

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

Eu tenho um `enum` `class` chamado `Example` da seguinte maneira:

```
export enum Example {
// enums pertercentes ao grupo A:
   enumA1,
   enumA2,
   enumA3,
// enums pertercentes ao grupo B:
   enumB1,
   enumB2,
   enumB3,
// enums pertercentes ao grupo C:
   enumC1,
   enumC2,
   enumC3;
}
```

É importante para meu projeto que todos os `enums` com os quais trabalho pertençam a `Example` (já que este é um argumento em um construtor de uma classe).

Como faço para usar a hierarquia / aninhamento de enum para atingir o seguinte:

Um método que testa se um enum é do grupo `A`, `B` ou `C`. Por exemplo, algo como `Example.enumA1.isGroupBelonging` (`Group.A`) ou `isGroupBelonging` (`Example.enumA1`, `Group.A`) seria um método público que retorna verdadeiro .

Ser capaz de fazer a mesma coisa com subgrupos do grupo `A`, `B` e `C`. Por exemplo, o grupo `A` pode ter subgrupos `a`, `b` e `c`. Em seguida, quero um método que faça algo como `Example.enumA1.isSubGroupBelonging` (`SubGroup.a`), que é um `booleano` *público*.

Uma maneira de fazer tudo isso sem precisar ter algum *nome* de `enum` elaborado que obstrua meu código. Por exemplo, seria bom poder apenas referir-se a `Example.enumA1` em minhas outras classes sem precisar fazer referência a ele usando algo como `Example.enumA1` (`Group.A`, `SubGroup.a`) ou `Example.enumA1.Group.A.SubGroup.a`

Comment: Não é melhor usar um pattern?

Comment: Qual pattern @VirgilioNovic ?

Comment: Basicamente eu não poderia dizer porque não sei o real problema, o que está na sua pergunta é vago de mais, não tem código de exemplo que a gente sempre pede aqui, um código que represente a sua duvida, geralmente uma `interface` de contrato e classes que implementa essa `interface`, alguma coisa estrutural ou até alguma coisa que possa ser mais simples.

Comment: Então não faz nenhum sentido seu comentário sobre o uso de pattern @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Se eu entendi, não seria mais simples ter vários enums separados pra cada grupo e ter um tipo que pode ser qualquer um desses grupos (`type abc = enumA1 | enumA2 | enumB1 ...`) ou até um grupo específico (`type a = enumA1 | enumA2 | enumA3`)? Assim você mantém os enums separados e usa os tipos para agrupar esses enums da forma que lhe convém

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei isso pode lhe ajudar, mas existe essa alternativa por meio de Object

```js
    const groupA = Object.freeze({
        A1: "A1",
        A2: "A1",
    })
    
    const groupB = Object.freeze({
        B1: "A1",
        B2: "A1",
    })
    
    const groupC = Object.freeze({
        ...groupA,
        ...groupB
    })
    
    Object.keys(groupC).includes(groupA.A1)
```